# Activating barcode scanner remotely via HTML iphone 4s

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, barcode

Is it possible to activate the barcode scanner from a HTML file residing in a web server? I can activate it if the HTML file is residing in my device, but it won't start if it's in the web server.

I think the problem lies

> script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="barcodescanner.js"

with , but I am unable to find what I should put for the source to run on the iPhone.

If there's a way to run it remotely, please let me know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Apple don't allow webApp to access to the camera. The only way is to have a native App. You can build a native app with Javascript using Titanium Appcelerator. You will be abble to access to camera then.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing using PhoneGap?

Comment: Yes ! But i don't know a lot about PhoneGap, so i can't help you any more :)

Comment: Thanks, but how do you do it using Titanium Appcelerator? I'm really new to all these programming.

Comment: Try the documentation, it's very simple : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Quick_Start